# Convert xy to x*y?

Tags: python, numpy, math, sympy

I am working on a project where user enters the input in the form of `xy` or `2x` or `2ab` but sympy is not able to understand that, i want to convert them into `x * y`, `2 * x`, `2 * a * b` respectively

Comment: there aren't many constraints on your question. Are you asking how to insert an asterix between characters in a string?

Comment: How do you tell the difference between `xy` meaning `x*y` and `xy` meaning "the variable named `xy`"? There's a reason programming languages don't do implicit multiplication...

Comment: Try e.g., `' * '.join(2ab)`

Comment: Suppose user enters an equation (sin(sqrt(xy)+2ab) * e^sqrt(x)) / sqrt(x) i want it to be converted into (sin(sqrt(x * y)+2 * a * b) * e^sqrt(x)) / sqrt(x)

Comment: Of course you'll have to watch out for something like 12x where you want 12*x and not 1*2*x

Comment: @ShadowRanger yes i agree that programming language don't do implicit multiplication but user enters the input in the form of xy than we need to somehow convert it into x * y else we can't give the output as per the users requirement

Comment: @ShadowRanger, this is a reasonable question in the `sympy` context.  Akshay should not have included `numpy` in the tags.  But while there is a `sympy` solution, it would be wise to avoid the ambiguity inherent in the expression.

Answer (score 1):

`sympy` is actually able to understand that. You need to use [`parsing`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html) to help for it:

```
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations,\
implicit_multiplication_application
transformations = (standard_transformations +
    (implicit_multiplication_application,))
print(parse_expr("xy", transformations=transformations))
```

**Output:**
x*y

Comment: thanks @mathfux it works for smaller equations but when it comes to bigger equations where we have like "(sin(sqrt(xy)+2ab) * e^sqrt(x)) / sqrt(x)" it fails

Comment: @AkshayR You need to apply more different kinds of transformations for other cases like `sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.convert_xor` for `^` operator and so on. Try to look them in docs. I guess there is no universal combination of transformations that would work for every case of user's input.

Comment: I can guess you want to split `xy` and `2ab`.  But why not `sin` or `sqrt`?  The program has to, in some sense, 'read your intentions.