# Using SymPy for plotting 3d functions on a discord bot

Tags: matplotlib, plot, discord.py, sympy

I am not very good with programming, but I have been developing this discord bot on python that basically aims to fulfill some of the basic math functions one can do on Wolfram Alpha. So I figured I would use SymPy to plot implicit, parametric and 3d curves using `plot_implicit`,`plot_parametric` and`plot3d` respectively. Firstly, say I want to plot a parametric function `(4t, t^2)`, the code fails to recognise `4t` as `4*t`. How do I fix that? Secondly, the 3d plotter shows me the same graph despite the fact I put `plt.clear()` in my code (Which shows an error, because it keeps saying 'clear' isn't defined). For reference, here is my code :

```py
x, y = symbols('x y')
        plt = plot3d(x * y, (x, -10, 10), (y, -10, 10), show=false)
        img = BytesIO()
        plt.save(img)
        img.seek(0)
        await ctx.send(file=discord.File(img, "graph.png"))
        plt.clear()
```

So, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

### Implicit multiplication

This issue was apparently solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311324/convert-xy-to-xy).

### Repeated plots

I cannot help you with this since I couldn't replicate the problem and I do not use the discord library but here are a few debugging ideas:

- Make absolutely sure it is not sending a file in the current working directory but rather from the BytesIO object.
- Send file names that are different each time like `graph1.png`, `graph2.png`, ...
- Maybe reimport `plot3d` inside the function for a completely fresh instance?

If these don't work, maybe write it in a comment so that others know that it did not solve the problem. Maybe they could help.

SymPy's plotting library is kind of buggy and fairly old. If it says that `.clear` is not an attribute then it might be best to not add that in.

### Code

Here is my code with my advice without the discord library stuff.

```py
from sympy import Expr
from io import BytesIO


def send_bio(bio: BytesIO):
    # I don't use the discord library so I can't help with that
    # this function stands in for the send file line
    # let's try to make the file name unique
    with open(f"output{hash(bio)}.png", "wb") as f:
        f.write(bio.getbuffer())


def my_plot(expr: Expr):
    # get the x and y variables with their specific traits
    # like rational=True or something like that
    x = [atom for atom in expr.expr_free_symbols if str(atom) == "x"][0]
    y = [atom for atom in expr.expr_free_symbols if str(atom) == "y"][0]

    from sympy.plotting import plot3d
    plt = plot3d(expr, (x, -10, 10), (y, -10, 10), show=False)
    img = BytesIO()
    plt.save(img)
    img.seek(0)
    send_bio(img)


def string_to_expr(s: str) -> Expr:
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64311324/convert-xy-to-xy
    from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
    from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations, \
        implicit_multiplication_application
    transformations = (standard_transformations +
                       (implicit_multiplication_application,))
    expr = parse_expr(s, transformations=transformations)
    return expr


if __name__ == '__main__':
    expr = string_to_expr("2xy")
    my_plot(expr)
    # next plot should be different
    expr = string_to_expr("x+y")
    my_plot(expr)
```